# StackExchange apps and LaTex rendering

Tags: applications

Is there any app which allows to browse Stack-Exchange sites and is able to interpret and render latex formulas inside the posts?

I have already tried StackAniwhere and Droidstack which apparently can't do it, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Are those the fancily formatted formulas they use on the Math site? They work fine for me in the mobile browser formatted version of the page, what are you hoping to get from one of the view-only apps that you can't get from the webpages?

Comment: Yes I can see them correctly on the web browser but I find it more confortable to open an app rather than open the browser and go to a web page.

Answer (score 2):

**I doubt that there is one one and that there will be one in the (near) feature.**

A look at [stackwrap4j](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper), the only Java Stackexchange Library that runs on Android, shows that the body (the content) of a post, which can be a question or an answer, is returned as plain String. The Tex equations are just included as plain Tex in that String and get rendered on the client side by the browser.

So, for example, [Droidstack](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.droidstack) would need a Tex library that parses the tex code and returns a picture with the compiled tex. And I am not aware of such a library *for Android*.